# Equalize data dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

```
Dictionary<DateTime, int> data1
Dictionary<DateTime, int> data2
```

not sorted

> ```
> if the dates in data1 is from **1/1/2000 - 1/1/2009**
> and the dates in data2 is from **1/1/2001 - 1/1/2007**
> then both Dictionaries<> should have the date ranging from **1/1/2001 - 1/1/2007**
> ```

it could be the other way around.

bascailly i need to remove the entries that are outside of the smaller range
how can i do this using c# and linq?

Comment: In this example yes. But it could be either one.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you want to remove from `data1` those entires `entry` where `entry.Key` is larger than January 1, 2001 and `entry.Key` is smaller than January 1, 2007? It seems that this is the case, but if so then I don't see the point of `data2`?

Comment: remove from data1 where entry.Key is smaller than January 1, 2001 and entry.Key is larger than January 1, 2007. data2 stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime min1 = data1.Keys.Min();
DateTime min2 = data2.Keys.Min();
DateTime max1 = data1.Keys.Max();
DateTime max2 = data1.Keys.Max();
if(min1 < min2 && max1 > max2) {
    data1 = ShrinkDictionary(data1, min2, max2);
}
else if(min2 < min1 && max2 > max1) {
    data2 = ShrinkDictionary(data2, min1, max1);
}
else {
    // this should never happen
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Here `ShrinkDictionary` is:

```
public Dictionary<DateTime, int> ShrinkDictionary(
    Dictionary<DateTime, int> dict, DateTime min, DateTime max) {
    return dict.Where(kvp => InRange(kvp.Key, min, max))
               .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

and `InRange` is the easily-generalizable method:

```
public bool InRange(DateTime date, DateTime min, DateTime max) {
    return (date >= min) && (date <= max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just need to remove entries from data2 (not to merge 2 dictionaries)

```
var min = data1.Keys.Min();
var max = data1.Keys.Max();
data2 = data2
    .Where(pair => pair.Key >= min && pair.Key < max)
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```